# How to Prevent to redirect page before javascript alert click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using below javascript code. I want to stay on same page till user click on alert.
After click on alert page should redirect to `SomePage.aspx`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        alert("Some text...");
        window.location = 'SomePage.aspx';
    }
</script>
```

Please let me know what I missed here. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of alert i think you need confirm box :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var conf = Confirm("Some text...");
    if(conf == true){
    window.location = 'SomePage.aspx';
    }
    else{ }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's Working but I dont want Cancel button on confirm. I only want OK button

Comment: @user3577774...this is a inbuilt confirm box of javascript you cannot change it...

Comment: @user3577774...and moreover after all its confirm box there should be 'ok' and 'cancel' buttons if user press ok he will go on other when press cancel then nothing will happen

Comment: Yes I know but I just want to show user that your record is updated and i want to just redirect the same page so user can show latest updated records

Comment: Yes I want to reload same page but before reload page , I just want to show message

Comment: @user3577774...strange if you want to show message then you will ask ok or cancel only .. and moreover if you want to reload same page then use window.location.reload()...

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.alert = function (al, $) {
            return function (msg) {                
                al.call(window, msg);                
                $(window).trigger("okbuttonclicked");
            };
        }(window.alert, window.jQuery);

        $(window).on("okbuttonclicked", function () {
            redirect();
        });

        function redirect() {
            window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
        }
        function myFunction() {
            alert("Some text...");
        }
</script>
```

**Html**

```
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Click" />
```

Note :- This function is execute on every `alert` ok button. But you also pass some additional parameter for preventing to execute.
And i also recommended to use confirm instead of this.